# Built-in VPN connection failure

Tags: networking, vpn

**Nevermind! I would still like to know why it doesn't worked with the built-in client. But I just found out that the ShrewSoft VPN client is available through the Software Center. Ok, I start to love linux! :-)**

I use the newest elementare OS (updated few minutes ago). I'm using a VPN connection to my office through the *ShrewSoft VPN* program in Windows and everything works fine. Since I don't want upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 10, I'm now switching to Linux and I need a VPN connection there too. But I can't get it to work with the built-in VPN client. elementary OS starts to connect and after a few seconds just shows a popup with message "The VPN connection '...' failed". What might be the problem?

The log in file /var/log/syslog says:

```
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 8424
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN connection 'XXXXX' (Connect) reply received.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Using interface ppp0
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pptp[8432]: nm-pptp-service-8424 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pptp[8436]: nm-pptp-service-8424 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: No route to host
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pptp[8436]: nm-pptp-service-8424 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pptp[8432]: nm-pptp-service-8424 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:487]: Call manager exited with error 256
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Modem hangup
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Connection terminated.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary pppd[8428]: Exit.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Aug  3 22:26:35 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Aug  3 22:26:39 vmelementary dbus[498]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
Aug  3 22:26:39 vmelementary dbus[498]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug  3 22:26:39 vmelementary kernel: [11391.182668] systemd-hostnamed[8456]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Aug  3 22:26:41 vmelementary NetworkManager[773]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

(IP and VPN profile name obfuscated)

**Settings**

```
Settings (VPN -> Advanced):
Authentication: [all checked]
[ ] Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)
[x] Allow BSD data compression
[x] Allow Deflate data compression
[x] Use TCP header compression
[x] Send PPP echo packets

Settings (IPv4 Settings)
Method: Automatic (VPN)
Addresses: [empty] (I can add addresses, since buttons disabled)
Additional DNS servers: [empty]
Additional search domains: [empty]

Settings (IPv4 Settings -> Routes...)
Route #1: 192.168.99.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.99.1
[ ] Ignore automatically obtained routes
[ ] Use this connection only for resources on its network
```

Comment: Lol, I earned the "Tubleweed" badge today... I don't think it's because of me. Too sad, that the elementary OS distro has no big community yet. I like this distro.